pyplot.hexbin doesn't use axis ranges correctly
My hexbin plot won't center at xC=0, yC=0 even though both axes are symmetric.

I've marked the center with green lines. As you can see, it does not match. The center of the last bins on the left are exactly where they are supposed to be, at -1.016*0.5. The center of the last bins on the right aren't. Same problem for the y-axis. The bottom is correct and the top isn't.
These are my axes:
xC = np.linspace(-1.016*0.5, 1.016*0.5, int(2e3))
yC = np.linspace(-0.756*0.5, (0.756*0.5), int(2e3))  

I then turn them into meshgrids:
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(xC[::10], yC[::10])  

The plot contains a function I(XX,YY,z) which I don't think I should explain here because it's not relevant to the problem.
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,6))
    colormapI_A_hex = plt.hexbin(XX.flatten(), 
                                     YY.flatten(), 
                                     (I(XX,YY,z).flatten(), 
                                     gridsize=(8,4), 
                                     cmap='gnuplot')
    colormapI_A_cbar_hex = fig.colorbar(colormapI_A_hex, label='Intensity $I_A$ [W/m$^2$]')
    plt.show()

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

You need to check the range and step size of your xC and yC arrays to ensure they are symmetric and properly cover the intended range as well as verifying the gridsize parameter to be sure that the hexagons are aligned as expected. The last step is to manually set the limits of the plot to ensure it centers correctly at (0,0).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xC = np.linspace(-1.016*0.5, 1.016*0.5, int(2e3))
yC = np.linspace(-0.756*0.5, 0.756*0.5, int(2e3))

XX, YY = np.meshgrid(xC[::10], yC[::10])

def I(XX, YY, z):
    return np.sin(XX) * np.cos(YY)  
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
colormapI_A_hex = plt.hexbin(XX.flatten(), 
                             YY.flatten(), 
                             I(XX, YY, z).flatten(), 
                             gridsize=(8, 4), 
                             cmap='gnuplot')

colormapI_A_cbar_hex = fig.colorbar(colormapI_A_hex, label='Intensity $I_A$ [W/m$^2$]')

plt.xlim([-1.016*0.5, 1.016*0.5])
plt.ylim([-0.756*0.5, 0.756*0.5])

plt.axhline(0, color='green', linestyle='--')
plt.axvline(0, color='green', linestyle='--')

plt.show()

which gives


Unfortunately it's still not centered. If you zoom in you can see that there is still an offset. Edit: ok I see. I have to use XX, YY = np.meshgrid(xC[::1], yC[::1]) always it seems.
